# Get dates that contain all selected products

Tags: c#, linq

I have a calendar app where you select various combinations of products- a service goes out and gets the available dates based on the calendar date range. A date is only "Available" if ALL selected products are available on a particular date.

```
class SelectedProduct
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}

class AvailableInventory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}


// List of selected products from user 
List<SelectedProduct> SelectedProducts;

// populated from service with all dates for all products
List<AvailableInventory> AvailableInventory;
```

I want to be able to say get list of Available Inventory for each date that contains inventory for all ID's in selected products.

This is (non-working) pusdo code of a possible solution, I just don't know linq well enough to get it right

```
var results = List<AvailableInventory>(); 

foreach (var group in AvailableInventory.GroupBy(x => x.Date))
{
    if (group.Contains(ALL ID's in SelectedProducts) 
    {
        results.AddRange(group); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: OK, What have you tried already? You should show your effort, and not just ask us to write code for you.

Comment: haha word- I can accomplish above with a very ugly loop- was looking for a more elegant LINQ solution- will post one sec.

Comment: is your `Date` property in `AvailableInventory` is an `int` or `Date`?

Comment: DateTime sorry- will edit.

Comment: ok, posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This groups inventory by date (ignoring the date portion), then selects only those groups that contain all selected product IDs, and finally selects all available inventory for the matching groups.

```
var results =
    AvailableInventory.GroupBy(i => i.Date.Date)
                      .Where(g => !SelectedProducts.Select(p => p.ID)
                                                   .Except(g.Select(i => i.ID))
                                                   .Any())
                      .SelectMany(g => g);
```

The result is a collection of `AvailableInventory`.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the date, then filter out groups that don't have all the SelectedProducts.

```
// List of selected products from user 
List<SelectedProduct> SelectedProducts = new List<SelectedProduct> {
    new SelectedProduct { ID = 1, Qty = 1 },
    new SelectedProduct { ID = 2, Qty = 2 },
};


// populated from service with all dates for all products
List<AvailableInventory> AvailableInventory = new List<AvailableInventory> {
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 1, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 11) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 2, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 11) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 1, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 12) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 2, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 13) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 1, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 14) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 2, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 14) },                
};

var query = AvailableInventory.GroupBy(i => i.Date)
    .Where(g => SelectedProducts.All(s => g.Any(i => i.ID == s.ID)));

foreach(var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", group.Key);

    foreach(var inventory in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Available: {0}", inventory.ID);
    }
}
```

This would output:

```
Date: 4/11/2014 12:00:00 AM
  Available: 1
  Available: 2
Date: 4/14/2014 12:00:00 AM
  Available: 1
  Available: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Try this

```
var result = AvailableInventory.Where(i => SelectedProducts.Any(x => x.ID == i.ID)).GroupBy(o => o.Date)
           .Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

This is the test data I used based on your class definition for `AvailableInventory` and `SelectedProduct`

```
// List of selected products from user 
List<SelectedProduct> SelectedProducts = new List<SelectedProduct> {
    new SelectedProduct { ID = 1, Qty = 2 },
    new SelectedProduct { ID = 2, Qty = 4 },
    new SelectedProduct { ID = 5, Qty = 10 }
};

// populated from service with all dates for all products
List<AvailableInventory> AvailableInventory = new List<AvailableInventory> {
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 1, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 01) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 2, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 02) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 3, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 02) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 4, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 10) },
    new AvailableInventory { ID = 5, Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 10) }
};
```

This should give you only the records with `ID = 1, ID = 2 and ID = 5` because that's what common between both `AvailableInventory` and `SelectedProducts` lists.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you actually *tried* something.

Given this:

```
List<SelectedProduct>    SelectedProducts   ;
List<AvailableInventory> AvailableInventory ;
```

Something like this will probably get what you want:

```
int[] DatesWithAllSelectedProductsAvailable =
        AvailableInventory
        .GroupBy( x => x.Date )
        .Where ( g => g.All( x => SelectedProducts.Any( p => p.ID == x.ID ) ) )
        .Select( x => x.Key )
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy( x => x )
        .ToArray()
        ;
```

Comment: Trust me, I tried... the whooshing sound of this going over my head was on par with a 747.